# Is it possible to measure the independent variable with part of the dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, time-series, correlation, repeated-measures

I have Beta as my independent variable and Economic value added (EVA) as my dependent variable. 
To calculate EVA I need to use Cost of capital and to calculate that I have to use Beta, so is it possible to use EVA as the dependent variable. thank you

> EVA= Net Operating Profit After Taxes (NOPAT) - (Capital * Cost of Capital)

Comment: Where is beta in this formula for EVA?

Comment: to calculate cost of capital, you need to get the cost of equity and to calculate that you need capital asset pricing model (CAPM) and to calculate that you need Beta :) thanks @PeterFlom

Comment: OK, well, what I would do is generate a bunch of random numbers for all the components of your model, do the calculations, and then run the model and see what happens. Then say "how do I tell if something real is happening or if it's just an effect of how the variables are calculated?"

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, what I would do is generate a bunch of random numbers for all the components of your model, do the calculations, and then run the model and see what happens. Then say "how do I tell if something real is happening or if it's just an effect of how the variables are calculated?"

I would write the R code for this, but I still don't have enough information to do so.

My guess is that you are going to have problems.

Comment: Could you amplify on your guess?  What is it about this circumstance that would cause "problems" and what would be their nature?  (Based on the limited information in the question it seems possible to me that the intended regression could work out perfectly well.)

Comment: It's just a guess, but usually when the DV is partly based on the IV, there is some artificial level of relationship.